# Regular expression in python -

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract the values of the below text

```
Paﬁent Name : Thomas Joseph MRNO : DQ026151?
Doctor : Haneef M An : 513! Gandar : Male
Admission Data : 19-Feb-2V'3‘¥T12:2'$ PM Bill No : IDOGIII.-H-17
Discharge Date : 22-Feb-20$? 1D:5‘F AM Bill Dale : E2-Feb-2017
```

extract only the values of the field names for example,

Thomas Joseph from the field name Pateint name, similarly for others field names and save the output to excel

Python code for the above

My attempt -

```
text = pt.image_to_string(img1)
print(text)
s = re.findall(r'\s:\s(\w+)', text)
print (s)
```

Comment: This job would be quite easier if you know what fields you will have in the text.

Comment: These are the field names. Paﬁent Name , MRNO , Doctor , An, Gandar , Admission Data, Bill No ,Discharge Date,Bill Dale

Comment: I want to extract the values from these field names..like Patient name is the field name then i need to extract "Thomas Joseph"

Comment: what I am saying is, are these field names always the same or they change from doc to doc or will there be addn of new fields sometimes?

Comment: No they are same for the docs

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is just a python regex question and you'd get a quicker answer on StackOverflow.

Comment: No i didnt get.I tried though.please help me to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be perfect but does the job almost.

```
import re
re.findall(r'(?<=: )\w{2}-\w{3}-\d{4}|(?<=: )\d{2}-\w{3}-\w{2}|(?<=: )\s?\w+\s?\w+\s?\w+',data)

#['Thomas Joseph MRNO','DQ026151','Haneef M An','513','Male','19-Feb-2V','IDOGIII','22-Feb-20','E2-Feb-2017']
```

Comment: Ya this seems better. but still cudnt extract all values of the fieldnames

Comment: ['Thomas Joseph MRNO',
 'DQ026151',
 'Haneef M An',
 '513',
 'Male\nAdmission Data',
 '19-Feb-2V',
 'IDOGIII',
 '22-Feb-20',
 'E2-Feb-2017']

Comment: above comment was my output.  i need still more better output

Comment: Can you please explain me the above code.

Comment: Check the chat room.

Answer (score 1):

As @spacedman correctly mentioned, this will answered quicker at StackOverflow. But you can use this to create a dictionary like this. There might be a better way but this is a quick work around.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
st = '''Pafient Name : Thomas Joseph MRNO : DQ026151?
Doctor : Haneef M An : 513! Gandar : Male
Admission Data : 19-Feb-2V'3‘¥T12:2'$ PM Bill No : IDOGIII.-H-17
Discharge Date : 22-Feb-20$? 1D:5‘F AM Bill Dale : E2-Feb-2017'''
st = st.decode('utf-8').replace('\n','')+'<eof>'
words = ['Pafient Name','MRNO','Doctor','An','Gandar','Admission Data','PM Bill No','Discharge Date','Bill Dale','<eof>']
print {words[i]:st[st.index(words[i])+len(words[i]):st.index(words[i+1])].replace(':','').strip() for i in range(len(words)-1)}
```

Comment: I tried to execute this.i got this error

Comment: Well, invest some of your time onto it and post *that* error onto StackOverflow if you are unable to resolve it.

Comment: File "<ipython-input-6-72de8d228cb9>", line 8
    print (words[i]:st[st.index(words[i])+len(words[i]):st.index(words[i+1])].replace(':','').strip()
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Try it in python 2.7, you might be using 3.x. Either way remove the dictionary comprehension and write a normal loop and try to print the substrings and then debug and find the type of error. This should give u some clue.

Comment: In which version of Python did u execute the above code.can u show me the output u have got.

Comment: `{'Discharge Date': u'22-Feb-20$? 1D5\u2018F AM', 'PM Bill No': u'IDOGIII.-H-17', 'Doctor': u'Haneef M', u'Pa\ufb01ent Name': u'Thomas Joseph', 'An': u'513!', 'Bill Dale': u'E2-Feb-2017', 'Gandar': u'Male', 'MRNO': u'DQ026151?', 'Admission Data': u"19-Feb-2V'3\u2018\xa5T122'$"}`  and 2.7.x version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56853/discussion-between-shyama-and-kiritee).